# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenos días amigos actualmente tengo un formulario llamado ventas, el cual envia los datos para editar la tabla ventas y detalle de ventas simultaneamente en mi controller tengo esto:

```
     $venta = Ofertas::find($id);
     $venta-> id_cliente = $request -> get('id_cliente');
     $venta-> observacion = $request->get ('observacion');
     $venta-> save();

     $id = $request -> get('id_producto');
     $cantidad = $request -> get('cantidad');
     $precio = $request -> get('precio');


     DetalleVentas::where('id', $id)->update([ 

    
    'precio' => $precio,
    'cantidad' => $cantidad
    ]);
```

pero cuando intento editar una venta me dice:

Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["501","301"]' for column `precio` at row 1 (SQL: update `detalleventas` set `precio` = ["501","301"], `cantidad` = ["1","2"], `detalleventas`.`updated_at` = 2021-06-15 19:03:39 where `id` = 131)

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas simplemente [update](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates)? Así simplemente haces: `DetalleVenta::where('id', $id)->update([ /* Array de Datos para actualizar */ ]);`

Comment: si hay varios productos que estan asociados a una venta que deseo editar

Comment: alli estoy iterando (los datos recibidos estan ok) el tema es que me da el error mencionado

Comment: ah ya ten entendi la variable que recupera varios registros es detalle porque tiene 8 productos asociados

Comment: gracias llevo dos días tratando de hacerlo pero no doy

Comment: Ese nuevo error `Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value` es porque estás intentando ingresar un valor que no corresponde a ese campo en su formato. Si es mandas un string y el campo es datetime, por ejemplo. O si es tu campo es de tipo integer y tratas de ingresar un string.

Comment: @gaidyjg segun veo esta tratando de insertar precio = ["501","301"] así todo junto y allí hay dos precios

Comment: Mira lo que te viene en el request de precio. Parece que el array es quien parece estarte dando problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas el método `find` perteneciente a la clase *Builder* de Eloquent puedes obtener como salida:

- null si es que no encuentra algún registro coincidente
- Un objeto si solo encontró un resultado asociado al valor pasado como argumento
- Una colección si es que varios registros coinciden con el valor pasado como argumento.<sup>1</sup> (*y considerando que el argumento recibido sea un array*)

Este último<sup>1</sup> parece ser tu caso ya que expones en los comentarios que la variable *`$detalle`* recupera al momento 8 registros.

Entonces debes además *iterar* a dicha variable para así poder acceder a los valores de cada una de las propiedades.

```
//Si $id es un array ya entonces lo dejas así, en caso contrario lo declaras de esta forma: `[$id]`
$detalle = DetalleVenta::find($id);     

foreach ($detalle as $detalleIndividual) {
    /*
        Aquí ya puedes acceder a las propiedades 
        cuyos valores deseas actualizar desde la variable $detalleIndividual
    */

    
    $detalleIndividual->ventas_id = $venta -> id;
    $detalleIndividual->id_producto = $id[$cont];
    $detalleIndividual->cantidad = $cantidad[$cont];
    $detalleIndividual->precio = $precio[$cont];
    $detalleIndividual->save();
}
```

Comment: Me arroja error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DetalleVenta' not found

Comment: si es correcto ya lo arregle ahora me dice Creating default object from empty value, lo reviso

Comment: despues de dos dias luchando nada me parece extraño, sigo intentando, gracias de todas formas

Comment: realice una modificacion del código guiando por lo que comentaron DetalleVenta::where('id', $id)->update([ /* Array de Datos para actualizar */ ]); voy a editarlo para mostrarlo